# Doing a difficult mongoDB find

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I need to find a document by an ID of a user which is in an array in that document, which looks like

```json
{
  "uuid": "000-000-000whatever",
  users: 
  [
    {
      "id":"id1",
      "role":"role1"
    },
    {
      "id":"id2",
      "role":"role1"
    }
  ]
}
```

and while I know that for that i could in mongo do "users.id" as a filter, i don't have a clue on how to do it using bson from Go.

The smartest thing I could figure was something along the line of

```golang
bson.M{"users": bson.A{bson.M{"id":id}}}
```

but needless to say, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the "same" in Go too:

```
bson.M{"users.id": id}
```